# React: setting state in container from within functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

So I have a container component which renders a functional component along with some other JSX. I am trying to change the state in that container from a button click that is occurring from inside that functional component. However I haven't found a good article on tackling this yet and I run into the problem of `this.setState() is not a function` or I completely break the current tab by trying to `trigger a setState call during a render` (more or less).

Here's some sample code to illustrate what I mean:

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <FunctionalComponent close={(type) => this.setState({ property: type })} />
    </div>
  }
};
```

Functional component:

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.close('stringvalue')}>Click to setState</button>
  );
};
```

Have also tried by creating a separate function inside the container and calling `this.setState()` from there, but the problem persists. Is this a context problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more idiomatic . . .

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
  }

  onClose(property) {
    this.setState({ property })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FunctionalComponent close={this.onClose} />
      </div>
    )
  }
};

const FunctionalComponent = ({ close }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={close.bind(null, 'stringvalue')}>Click to setState</button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your `props.close` function is called on each render as you're not passing a function but calling it.

onClick requires a function.

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  function onClick() {
    props.close('stringvalue');
  }
  return (
   <button onClick={onClick}>Click to setState</button>
  );
};
```

or

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  return (
   <button onClick={() => props.close('stringvalue')}>Click to setState</button>
  );
};
```